# How to import Exchange calendars in Google Calendar (No Desktop Outlook)

Tags: sync, exchange, google-calendar

I would like to import my calendar from my company Exchange 2010 server as a new calendar in my private Google account. The primary use is to easy my planning when at home with my laptop.

I already have access to both the Google and Exchange calendars on my Android phone, but the size of the screen makes it rather difficult to plan anything serious.

Note that

- I run OSX on my laptop
- I would prefer a Internet based solution to any software on my own laptop.
- I do *not* want an Outlook add-in
- I do *not* want to include the work related events in my main calendar
- I do *not* want a mobile solution
- I can pay for the solution